# Initially closed tree [JsTree]

Tags: jstree

So I'm using the JsTree Plugin and I want all the tree to be initially closed. I don't know why I have it initially opened. By the way I'm creating the leaves dynamically through Jquery (append). Thanks in advance.

My code used to be like this :

```
<div id="demo2" class="demo">
<ul>
<li class="jstree-open"><a href="#">Root node 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li id="One"><a href="#">Child node 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child node 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ADV_SEARCH</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child node 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Root node 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So I simply changed `<li class="jstree-open">` to `<li class="jstree-closed">` for the nodes who have children.

Comment: Could you provide  your code? Or better working jsfiddle?

Comment: Well I found the answer thank you I'll provide the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since I didn't really understand this plugin pretty well, I used class="jstree-open" in the li tag and I had no idea what it meant, so by curiosity I put closed instead of open and I got exactly what I wanted. Then I discovered by chance that the class really existed. Anyway as I said in different post JsTree really needs more Documentation because I find it to be a great plugin.